# UICollectionView continuous scroll while loading paginated data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, pinterest

I'm trying to replicate the way the Pinterest SDK's example app: (https://github.com/pinterest/ios-pdk) continuously scrolls while loading pins, but I can't quite get it right.  Can anyone see what I'm missing?  This code loads the first page (first 25 pins) but when you get to the bottom of those does not reload the next 25 pins.  The example app (and SDK) are written in Obj-C so I'm translating as I go but am not very familiar with Obj-C.

```
    private let reuseIdentifier = "PinCell"

    class PinCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

        var pins = [PDKPin]()
        var imageArray = [UIImage]()
        var boardID = String()
        var fetchingMore = false
        var currentResponseObject =  PDKResponseObject()


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            PDKClient.sharedInstance().getBoardPins(boardID, fields: ["id", "image", "note", "link"], withSuccess: { (responseObject :PDKResponseObject!) -> Void in

                self.currentResponseObject = responseObject

                print(responseObject.pins().first!.descriptionText)
                guard let pinsAsPDKPin = responseObject.pins() as? [PDKPin] else {print("problem downloading boards");return}
                for pin in pinsAsPDKPin {
                    self.pins.append(pin)
                    print("\(pin.descriptionText) link =  \(pin.url)")
                }


                let imageURLs = pinsAsPDKPin.map { $0.largestImage().url }

                for url in imageURLs {

                    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

                    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {(data, reponse, error) in

                        guard let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) else {return}
                        guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {return}
                        self.imageArray.append(image)

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                            self.collectionView?.reloadData()

                        })

                    })

                    task.resume()
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()

                })





                })  { (err :NSError!) -> Void in
                    print("error NSError: \(err)")
            }

        }


        override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

            let imageURLs = pins.map {$0.largestImage().url}

            for url in imageURLs {
                guard let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) else {return}
                guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {return}
                imageArray.append(image)
            }


        }


        // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

        override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
            // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
            return 1
        }


        override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return self.imageArray.count
        }

        override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PinCollectionViewCell



            cell.pinText?.text = self.pins[indexPath.row].descriptionText


            if imageArray.count > 0 {

                if let readyImage = imageArray[indexPath.row] as? UIImage {

                    cell.pinImage?.image = readyImage
                }
            }



            return cell
        }



            override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



                if self.fetchingMore == false && currentResponseObject.hasNext() && self.pins.count - indexPath.row < 5 {

                    self.fetchingMore = true

                    self.currentResponseObject.loadNextWithSuccess({ (nextResponseObject :PDKResponseObject!) -> Void in



                        self.fetchingMore = false
                        self.currentResponseObject = nextResponseObject

                        guard let unwrappedArrayOfPins = nextResponseObject.pins() as? [PDKPin] else {return}

                        for pin in unwrappedArrayOfPins {
                            self.pins.append(pin)
                        }

 for url in imageURLs {

                        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

                        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {(data, reponse, error) in

                            guard let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) else {return}
                            guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {return}
                            self.imageArray.append(image)

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                                self.collectionView?.reloadData()

                            })

                        })

                        task.resume()
                    }



                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                            self.collectionView?.reloadData()

                        })




                        }) { (err :NSError!) -> Void in
                            print("error NSError: \(err)")
                    }

                }

            }
```

Comment: try placing some breakpoints (click the line number on the left, if you're using Xcode) and see if it makes it to certain points. Points I'd recommend: • Check if your code makes it inside of the `if` statement in `willDisplayCell` • Check if the newly loaded pins are added to your `pins` array • Check if `self.collectionView?.reloadData()` is called in that same method.

Comment: Good suggestions, thanks!  Yes it makes in in willDIsplayCell, yes pins are added and yes .reloadData() is called.  In the initial pull down, I have 25 pins, when willDisplayCell fires (at the end of the collection view scroll I think) another 25 pins are added to my count, however the additional 25 aren't displayed.  And there are more than 50 pins on the board I'm testing so I'm not pulling down the next 25 etc.  Still not sure...

Comment: Well, I didn't change anything but today this code is working and loading the paginated pins...however, the UI is really glitchy as the images flicker.  How can I make this smoother?